# How to determine the full file path in which a Clojure namespace is defined?

Tags: clojure

For example:

```
(defn show-full-path-of-ns [namespace-symbol]
    ;; how to do it?
    )

(show-full-path-of-ns 'ring.middleware.session)
;; => ~/.m2/repository/ring/ring-core/1.7.1/ring-core-1.7.1.jar!ring/middleware/session.clj
```

(Yes I know it's possible to split a namespace into more than one files, but we may ignore that.)

Comment: A namespace may also be defined by no files at all, e.g. because it was defined in the REPL, or loaded from a jar, or loaded from the network, etc. This is just not a question with a well-defined answer. Consider why you want this, and look for a different solution to that problem.

Comment: @amalloy I came across a namespace in a project that depends on a lot of libraries. So I need to find where it is defined so as to read its source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution to the problem. It works for jar files in the classpath, but it might give you some idea.

```
(ns so.find-namespaces
    (:require
        [clojure.tools.namespace.find :as f]
        [clojure.java.classpath :as cp])
    (:import
        [java.util.jar JarFile]))

(apply hash-map (->> (cp/classpath)
                     (filter (memfn isFile))
                     (mapcat #(interleave (f/find-namespaces-in-jarfile (JarFile. %)) (repeat (.getCanonicalPath %))))))
```

Anyway, if there is a solution it is probably in [here](http://clojure.github.io/tools.namespace/)